# Prove the Positive Orthant is Open (Proof Verification)

Tags: solution-verification

I'm practicing my proof-writing and was hoping you could let me know if this proof looks good. I would like to know if the proof is incorrect, if there are parts that are overly wordy/complicated, or if I'm missing some element of a proof that is helpful to see, if not strictly necessary.

**The Prompt:**

Prove that the positive orthant R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup> is an open subset of R<sup>m</sup>.

**My Proof:**
Let **x** be an arbitrary element of R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup>. Let ε = inf x<sub>i</sub> for all i = 1,...,m. Now define open ball B<sub>ε</sub>(x) = {y ∈ R<sup>m</sup> | ||**x**-**y**|| < ε}. The closest point to outside of R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup> will be in a straight line from **x** in the dimension of **x** which is closest to 0 (call it dimension k, so x<sub>k</sub>=inf x<sub>i</sub>). Thus, set all values of y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> except for when i=k. Then:

||**x**-**y**|| = sqrt((x<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>-y<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>)+0+0...) = x<sub>k</sub> - y<sub>k</sub> < ε

x<sub>k</sub> - y<sub>k</sub> < inf x<sub>i</sub>

x<sub>k</sub> - inf x<sub>i</sub> < y<sub>k</sub>

0 < y<sub>k</sub>

So y<sub>k</sub> > 0 and since y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> ∈ R<sub>+</sub> for all other i, y ∈ R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup>. Since any element of R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup> has an open ball in R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup> surrounding it, R<sub>+</sub><sup>m</sup> is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good start, but then it starts getting a bit wordy / overcomplicated. Here are a few points that could make things smoother.

- You use $x_i$ without defining them. You may want to write "let $x = (x_1,\dots,x_m) \in \mathbb{R}_+^m$".
- Then, writing
  $$
  \epsilon = \inf_{i=1,...,m} x_i > 0
  $$
  would be better notation.
- You do not define the norm $\| \cdot \|$. Maybe it is given before, but we do not know this. Apparently, it is the Euclidean norm.
- The main issue is this mysterious sentence "The closest point to outside of $\mathbb{R}_+^m$ will be in a straight line from x in the dimension of x which is closest to $0$ (call it dimension k, so $x_k=\inf x_i$)" It is not clear what you mean here, and this relies a lot on two-dimensional intuition. What you really want to show is that the ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is indeed included in the positive octant. This means, take
  $$
  y = (y_1,\dots,y_n) \in B_{\epsilon}(x),
  $$
  and show that $y \in \mathbb{R}_+^m$, i.e. that $y_i > 0$ for each $i$. Can you get this, using triangle inequality and your definition of $\epsilon$?